# Stacking properties by specifying multiple Maven profiles on the command line

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml

I finally got my test automation running using JUnit4 `@Category` for each test; they are marked as either `PriorityHigh`, `PriorityMedium`, or `PriorityLow`.

In my `pom.xml` I have each set up as a profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>PriorityHigh</id>
    <properties>
        <testcase.category>com.categories.PriorityHigh</testcase.category>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>PriorityMedium</id>
    <properties>
        <testcase.category>com.categories.PriorityMedium</testcase.category>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>PriorityLow</id>
    <properties>
        <testcase.category>com.categories.PriorityLow</testcase.category>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Which is then used in the plugin section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <groups>${testcase.category}</groups>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <automation.driver>${browser.name}</automation.driver>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My issue is when I want to test both Medium and High, I specify

```
-P PriorityHigh,PriorityMedium
```

But instead of adding/concatenating, they overwrite and so only Medium tests run. To add extra difficulty, since `pom.xml` complains that ${testcase.category} only exists in profiles, and no default, I had to add this:

```
<testcase.category>com.categories.PriorityHigh,com.categories.PriorityMedium,com.categories.PriorityLow</testcase.category>
```

in case no profile is specified.

So two questions:

1. How to get the profiles to stack correctly in the "groups" node?
2. A better way to work it if no profile is specified (all tests should run)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to ditch profiles and just use system properties:

```
<properties>
  <testcase.category>com.categories.PriorityHigh,com.categories.PriorityLow</testcase.category>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <groups>${testcase.category}</groups>
    ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then:

```sh
mvn verify -Dtestcase.category=com.categories.PriorityHigh
# runs PriorityHigh tests

mvn verify -Dtestcase.category=com.categories.PriorityHigh,com.categories.PriorityLow
# runs PriorityHigh and PriorityLow tests

mvn verify
# runs PriorityHigh and PriorityLow tests
```

If you don't want to have to specify the fully qualified category class name on the Maven command line, you could use the Build Helper plugin to qualify the names for you:

```
<properties>
  <testcase.category>PriorityHigh,PriorityLow</testcase.category>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>build-fq-testcase-category</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>fq.testcase.category</name>
        <regex>([^,]+)</regex>
        <value>${testcase.category}</value>
        <replacement>com.categories.$1</replacement>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <groups>${fq.testcase.category}</groups>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then:

```sh
mvn verify -Dtestcase.category=PriorityHigh
# just run PriorityHigh tests

mvn verify
# run PriorityLow and PriorityHigh tests

# etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! A much simpler solution. My only complaint is that, in using the Build Helper plugin, that fq.testcase.name is not recognized as a value in the IDE so it always shows the value in error. Code still compiles and tests still run, but the OCD in me doesn't like the name in red.

Comment: Maybe you could trick your IDE by adding an `<fq.testcase...>` property to the `<properties>` section with an empty or any value

Comment: For some reason, when I add the blank property, it stops the Categories from working. In other words, it runs all tests regardless of priority.